# Merging various backend requests in the express res.send()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, callback

I'm trying to make several asynchronous backend calls to generate a JSON response in my express API. Because of the nature of the API, I have 3 requests that are being made that are dependent on each other in some way.

> Request 1: Returns an Array of values that are used to make request 2. Each value will be used as a mapping for the remaining requests. That is to say, it will be a unique identifier used to map the response from the requests in Request 3.

> Request 2 (Parallel Batch): A request is made using each value from the Array returned in request 1. Each of these returns a value to be used in each of the Request 3s. That is to say, it's a 1-to-1

> Request 3 (Parallel Batch): This request takes the response from Request 2, and makes a 1-to-1 follow up request to get more data on that specific mapping (the id from request 1)

I would like the final data I send to the consumer to look like this:

```
{
  id1: details1,
  id2: details2,
  id3: details3,
  ...
}
```

Here is the code I have so far...

```
app.get("/artists/:artist/albums", (req, res) => {
  console.log("#############")
  const artistName = req.params.artist
  let response = {};
  let s3Promise = s3.listAlbums(artistName)
  let albumDetailsPromises = []

  s3Promise
    .then((data) => {
      data.map((album) => {
        // Each album name here will actually be used as the unique identifier for 
        // the final response
        
        // Build an Array of promises that will first fetch the albumId, then use
        // that album id to fetch the details on the album
        albumDetailsPromises.push(
          discogs.getAlbumId(artistName, album).then(  // Returns a promise
            ({ data }) => {
              let masterId = data.results[0].id
              let recordName = data.results[0].title

              // Storing the album name to carry as a unique id alongside the promise
              return [album, discogs.getAlbumDetails(masterId) // Returns a promise ]
            }
          )
        )
      })
    })
    .then(() => {
      // When all the albumIds have been fetched, there will still exist a promise in the 
      // second index of each element in the albumDetailsPromises array
      Promise.all(albumDetailsPromises)
        .then((namedPromises) => {
          namedPromises.map(
            (album) => {
              let albumName = album[0]  // Unique Id
              let albumDetailPromise = album[1] 

              // Resolving the albumDetailsPromise here, and storing the value on
              // a response object that we intend to send as the express response
              albumDetailPromise
                .then(
                  ({ data }) => {
                    response[albumName] = data
                  })
                .catch(err => response[albumName] = err)
            })
        })
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
})
```

As of now, everything seems to be working as expected, I just can't seem to figure out how to "await" the response object being updated at the end of all these Promises. I've omitted `res.send(response)` from this example because it's not working, but that's of course my desired outcome.

Any advice is appreciated! New to javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactored using async/await...

```
app.get("/artists/:artist/albums", async (req, res) => {
  const artistName = req.params.artist
  let response = {};

  let albums = await s3.listAlbums(artistName)
  const promises = albums.map(async (album) => {
    let result = await discogs.getAlbumId(artistName, album)
    try {
      let masterId = result.data.results[0].id
      let tempRes = await discogs.getAlbumDetails(masterId)
      return [album, tempRes.data]
    } catch (error) {
      return [album, { "msg": error.message }]
    }
  })

  responses = await Promise.all(promises)
  responses.map(data => { response[data[0]] = data[1] })

  res.send(response)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend rewriting this using `async/await` as it helps to reduce nesting. You can also extract the logic the get the album-details into a separate function, as this also increases the readability of the code. Something like this (this still needs error-handling, but it should give you a start):

```
app.get("/artists/:artist/albums", async (req, res) => {
    const artistName = req.params.artist;
    const albumNames = await s3.listAlbums(artistName);
    const result = {};
    
    const albumDetailPromises = albumNames.map(albumName => requestAlbumDetails(discogs, artistName, albumName));
    const resolvedAlbumDetails = await Promise.all(albumDetailPromises);
    
    // map desired response structure
    for(const albumDetail of resolvedAlbumDetails) {
      result[albumDetail.albumName] = albumDetail.albumDetails;
    }
    
    res.json(result);
});

async function requestAlbumDetails(service, artistName, albumName) {
    const albumInfo = await service.getAlbumId(artistName, albumName);
    const masterId = albumInfo.results[0].id;
    const albumDetails = await service.getAlbumDetails(masterId);
    return { albumName, albumDetails };
}
```

To answer your question how you could do it with your code:
You'd need to wait for all details to be fulfilled using another `Promise.all` call and then just `send` the response in the `then`-handler:

```
Promise.all(albumDetailsPromises)
  .then((namedPromises) => {
    const detailsPromises = namedPromises.map(
      (album) => {
        let albumName = album[0];
        let albumDetailPromise = album[1];

        return albumDetailPromise
          .then(({ data }) => {
            response[albumName] = data;
          })
          .catch(err => response[albumName] = err);
      });
    return Promise.all(detailsPromises)
      .then(() => res.json(response));
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I tried refactoring with async / await and it's MUCH clearer. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Happy to help, I would appreciate if you accepted my answer, thank you :)